# Nested recyclerview view like play Play Store app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make nested recyclerview with CardView like Play Store app home page, so far it works but not as smoothly than Play Store.

When recycler view scroll position is 0 and i start dragging right, edge effect appears as expected but soon i continue dragging up it looks like my horizontal recyclerview loses focus and parent vertical one takes over. From Play Store app you won't lose focus when continuing dragging up after a horizontal drag from edges.
I insist that it only happends when i'm on recycler view edges.

[image]

In addition to this (and this is maybe related), it looks easier to initiate a horizontal scroll from Play Store app, i mean if you drag with an 30° angle from horizontal with PlayStore app horizontal scroll is initiated, but from my app it seems i need a max 10° angle to initiate mine otherwise vertical scroll take over.

Here's mine vertical recycler view code (inside a coordinator layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          style="@style/AppStyle.Fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="weather / places"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

-

```
mList.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( getContext( ),
                                                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                                                     false ) );
mList.setAdapter( new HomeAdapter( ) );
```

Here is nested horizontal one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="@dimen/screen_padding">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="hello world"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:background="@color/divider"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"/>
```

```
ListViewHolder( View itemView )
{
    super( itemView );

    list.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( getContext( ),
                                                        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                                                        false ) );
    list.setHasFixedSize( true );
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper( );
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView( list );
    list.setAdapter( new ListAdapter( ) );
    list.setNestedScrollingEnabled( false );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found solution, from nested horizontal recyclerview add :

```
childHorizontalList.addOnScrollListener( new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener( )
{
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged( RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState )
    {
        super.onScrollStateChanged( recyclerView, newState );

        parentVerticalList.setLayoutFrozen( newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Wow nice! Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: setLayoutFrozen is deprecated now. Now we should call suppressLayout(bool)